# Why exit and logout both exists?

Tags: login

At least in Ubuntu, in a normal shell, running `logout` will show a message, tell me that I'm not in a login shell. But in a login shell, `logout` and `exit` do the same thing, as far as I know. So, why they both exist, why `exit` isn't enough?

Comment: Please provide more details; what product/release are you talking about, what shell (a GUI shell such as GNOME Shell? or a terminal shell such `xterm`, `gnome-terminal` etc?. or a command shell such as `bash`, `csh` etc?).

Comment: If you're talking about bash, I think it's just a bit of compatibility for `csh`

Answer (score 3):

I guess you refer to a **terminal emulator** when referring to a "normal shell". Your login shell started when your graphical desktop started. Your terminal emulator exposes you to an interactive shell that is not a login shell. Hence, you cannot logout there.

When you **log in on a TTY**, you drop to an interactive login shell. `logout` will log you out. `exit` will terminate the shell, but since it was the login shell, will also log you out.

Try the following: open another shell, e.g. `dash` or `sh`. You drop to an interactive shell. Try `logout`: you see the same message you saw in your interactive shell: you are not in a login shell, so you cannot log out.

You can only exit that shell with `exit`, then you return to the login shell, where you can `logout` explicitly, or `exit`, which will implicitly log you out as well.

Comment: Thank you. So, as my understanding, is `logout` executing `loginctl terminate-session ***` and `exit` only run the call `exit()`?

Comment: I did not look in the source code, and you did not ask about it. Surely, both commands have different meanings as I illustrated in my answer.